# Can't install gulp-babel with npm

Tags: npm, gulp, babeljs

npm gives me the following error:

```
No compatible version found: left-pad@0.0.3
```

Tried to install left-pad with npm and got the same error.

Comment: well what version of npm are you using? if 3+, then you need to be careful about loading modules that use the new flat node_modules structure.

Comment: @Bosworth99 I'm using 3.7.3. Are you suggesting that I downgrade to earlier version? Not sure what the implications of the flat node_modules structure would be.

Comment: no you definitely want the newest version, but some modules are incompatible. It doesn't sound like that's the issue, at any rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

left-pad was unpublished from npm, and once something is unpublished you can't publish it again. now anything that has dependencies on the versions of left-pad that were removed need to be updated.

see [here](https://github.com/azer/left-pad/issues/4) for discussion.

Edit: turns out the author of left-pad [removed all his packages from NPM](https://medium.com/@azerbike/i-ve-just-liberated-my-modules-9045c06be67c#.98i1ysdv0) because NPM caved to kik's lawyers and seized control of the author's kik related repo. Pretty hilarious such a trivial library has brought large chunks of the ecosystem down.

Comment: Seems like there ought to be an error message for that.